# A library that can be loaded/required as well as be used as a program

Tags: ruby, load, command-line-interface, require

I would like to write a small Ruby library. Sometimes I want to use it as a standalone CLI application, and sometimes as a loadable library. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is going to be a simple file, the common way is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# content of the library
...

if $0 == __FILE__
  # command to be executed only when the file is called by a command
end
```

If you want to make it a gem, the standard way is to write the executable Ruby script in a file (let's say `foo`) under the `/bin` directory within the gem directory, and add the following to the `*.gemspec` file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  ...
  s.executables << "foo"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thx, not fiddling with gems yet.